# Is there a strategy on how to migrate from NodeJS CJS + Babel to NodeJS MJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, es6-modules, commonjs

I want to slowly migrate my NodeJS project to a module-style project. And while there are many bits of knowledge on how to use cjs from mjs and wise versa, I have also Babel in the loop, and I'm super confused about what's going on.

At the moment I have a CommonJS node project (that started on node v4). About 80% of the project look like MJS (using imports and exports) thanks to Babel. Now I'm slowly changing small files to native MJS in order to convert the whole project.

I noticed that babel would by default transpile MJS files to JS files. So 1) imports are not working; 2) I don't want to use Babel with MJS because I hope that I can get rid of it eventually. Thus I added `**/*.mjs` files to the ignored list in the `.babelrc` file, and fixed file extension to `.js, .cjs` in the `babel/regiter` require code.

After this NodeJS keeps complaining that `.mjs` files have unknown token *export*. If I run that single `.mjs` file — everything is good, unless it imports a cjs file that has `import` in it, and was not transpiled by babel, as I didn't run everything from a root file that registers babel…

Is there a way to have babel transpiling cjs (js) files and keeping mjs files as-is, while node interprets mjs files as native modules?